# Determining speed of shake

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to determine the speed at which someone is shaking their iPhone?  This would be the time they start moving to the ending point where they are now going back to the origin.  Basically it is one swipe that I'd like to measure the speed of.  This discussion comments on initial speed: http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=8297689#8297689.  It seems that the important component of distance is lacking in the iPhone to get a good measure of speed.

Comment: It's probably just me but the first thing I thought of when reading this question is its applicability to the p0rn industry :-) Apologies in advance if that offends anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, it sounds like all you'd need to do would be to numerically integrate the acceleration twice to get the distance traveled. For instance, look at
[Calculate the position of an accelerating body after a certain time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153507/calculate-the-position-of-an-accelerating-body-after-a-certain-time)

Note that you'll have to subtract gravity from the measured acceleration to get the kinetic acceleration, which is what you should integrate. As for how to do that, re: GoatRider's comment: I might try storing the last measured acceleration whose magnitude was equal to gravity (I think that's 1 in iPhone units?). Then for each acceleration measurement you make whose magnitude is greater than 1, subtract the last known acceleration of gravity - this will need to be a vector subtraction - and use that as the kinetic acceleration. Of course, this assumes that the user keeps the phone in the same orientation throughout the swipe, which I think would be approximately true.

Unfortunately, there's no technique you can use to distinguish between gravitational acceleration and kinetic acceleration in general - that is, a determined user could always find a way to fool whatever algorithm you might come up with. (Trivia: that's called the *equivalence principle*, and it's the foundation of Einstein's theory of general relativity)

Comment: How would you distinguish the shake from tilt/gravity?

Comment: Isn't that what he explained starting at the last sentence of the 2nd paragraph?

Comment: How could you verify that your speed calculations are even within the right ballpark?

Comment: Try it and see I guess? If they're not even in the right ballpark you're probably using the math incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do the calculations yourself. Each acceleration event you receive will tell you the relative G-forces registering on the accelerometer and the time at which the event was recorded. You'll have to sample over several events and interpolate. Here's more info on the acceleration event itself:

[UIAcceleration Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAcceleration_Class/Reference/UIAcceleration.html)

Comment: Looks like I'll need a radar gun.